# Deploying SwampDragon on Apache

Tags: python, django, apache, swampdragon

I am using Apache with mod_wsgi to run django server in production.The blog [here](http://swampdragon.net/blog/deploying-swampdragon/) describes how to deploy SwampDragon on NGNIX. There's issue [here](https://github.com/jonashagstedt/swampdragon/issues/135) which discusses a bit about how to deploy SwampDragon on Apache but its not very clear.  How can I deploy SwampDragon on Apache ? will it be required to put server.py file in root folder ?

Update:

I deployed the SwampDragon using Proxy. I am looking for way to deploy the same using mod_wsgi similar to Django. How to write wsgi script for running a python script ?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, SwampDragon is just an add on for Django, so would it not be as simple as following the tutorial at http://swampdragon.net/documentation/adding-swampdragon-to-an-existing-django-project/ and running Django on Apache with their tutorial at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/ ?

Comment: I know how to deploy a django project using modwsgi, but I was not able to figure out how to deploy SwampDragon using that. So, I deployed it using Proxy and mod_proxy_wstunnel in Apache. I want to run a python script using modwsgi, but I was not able to figure out how to write a wsgi application for that.

Comment: So, again, since SwampDragon is just an extension of Django, I'd think you should be able to just add the Django application using mod_wsgi. Did you check out the second link above? It seems to me that simply adding the definitions outlined at http://swampdragon.net/documentation/adding-swampdragon-to-an-existing-django-project/ and then creating a wsgi.py as outlined in https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/howto/deployment/wsgi/ should work.

Comment: Django creates wsgi.py by its own.I want to create a wsgi file to run server.py (as mentioned in swampdragon docs). Can you help me figure out how to write a wsgi.py file for running server.py

Comment: You want the apache server to run another server? Why not just run it directly? I haven't ran any other servers through apache before.

Comment: I will be happy if I can do that. But I was not able to figure out that, so I ran server.py on private ip just like we run django runserver  and configured apache to point traffic to that.

Comment: The issue with running server.py will be that the service will not be multi-threaded. I believe that what you are needing to know, with regards to running the WSGI application directly, is contained in the links I sent you. Other than that, I'm afraid I cannot offer anything more on it. Perhaps a Django or Apache (httpd) group on IRC would be of service.